# Libraries available on Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

Are there any libraries available by default in the Android NDK? If not, can I use any c++/c library, as long as I include it myself?

In particular, I need compression, encryption, regex and sqlite. I was thinking of using `zlib`, `crypto++`, `sqlite`(duh!) and `boost`, but can use anything else if it is already available.

Also, if nothing is available built-in, would you recommend something other then my above choice (I prefer public-domain when possible, or BSD or similar)

Comment: Why do you need all that with NDK? If you're going out to SQLite, for instance, you aren't likely to get any noticeable performance boost over accessing SQLite from Java. Read ["When to Develop in Native Code"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#choosing) for more info on this point.

Comment: @Ted-Hopp It is an app that runs on multiple platforms, (windows and android currently, hoping for more later). The main engine of the app is in c++, so that I won't need to rewrite it for each platform. The engine stores data in SQLite tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you need to download the NDK package from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html and investigate the documentation from the package. I'm sure you will get the answers to most of your questions.
And quick answer to your questions. Yes there are libraries by default in the Android NDK. For example standard C and C++ libraries.

Comment: I now about the standard libraries. I was asking about functionality not included by standard libraries.

Comment: There are also other libraries, in the mentioned document you can find the description of them.

Comment: which standard c and c++ library are available? cause first sentence in documentation states: "The Android platform provides a very minimal C++ runtime support library (libstdc++). This minimal support does not include, for example: Standard C++ Library support (except a few trivial headers),C++ exceptions support, RTTI support"

Answer (score 4):

- SQLite is available on Android via abstracted [database access](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) in Java. The ‍`.so` itself is private. You can of course compile your own SQLite library if you require modifications, but in general you should access it from Java. I have done this for encryption purposes.
- `zlib` is available to the NDK
- `crypto++` could of course be compiled via the NDK
- Boost certainly works on Android/NDK (I'm currently using it heavily)

Comment: How much does it add to my `.apk` using the boost regex? would you recommend a different one?

Comment: I cannot say for sure as I'm using much more than that from Boost. I imagine regex alone is quite small, however.

Answer (score 2):

By default Android NDK delivers some libraries, so called 'stable native APIs' (http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html):

- `libc` (C library) headers
- `libm` (math library) headers
- JNI interface headers
- `libz` (Zlib compression) headers
- `liblog` (Android logging) header
- OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 (3D graphics libraries) headers
- `libjnigraphics` (Pixel buffer access) header (for Android 2.2 and above).
- A Minimal set of headers for C++ support
- OpenSL ES native audio libraries
  Android native application APIS

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer with respect to Crypto++....

Crypto++ has a wiki page with build instructions from the command line at [Android (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29). The process will create the various libraries and show you how to build `cryptest.exe` to verify the library on a device. But you will still need to create you wrapper project using Android's build system.

Piotr Morgwai Kotarbiński has a page on building the Crypto++ library with Android's modified build system. See [Building Crypto++ with NDK toolchain](http://morgwai.pl/ndkTutorial/#heading_toc_j_2). I don't believe Piotr's article verifies the library on a device.